# How can I show the custom field value in custom post type plugin

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I added a new custom field to my custom post type named game_offer.

Now, I have a plugin widget that allows me to show the latest custom post types. 
In this plugin I want to be able to also put the custom field in the loop.

To show the custom field I tried this code that I have used before:

```
<?php the_field('game_offer'); ?>
```

When I view the page I see this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function the_field()
```

I used the following code inside the loop:

```
if( $pq->have_posts() ) :
?>  
    <div class="flex">
        <?php while($pq->have_posts()) : $pq->the_post(); ?>

          <div class="left">
            <?php
                $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    echo '<div class="menu_image" style="background: url('. $url.')">';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<div class="menu_image fallback_menus_image">';
                    echo '</div>';
                }  
            ?>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="left">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                        <ul>
                            <li><?php echo the_field('game_offer'); ?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

          </div>  

<?php wp_reset_query();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

My entire plugin looks like this in case needed:

```
function n2wp_latest_cpt_init() {
if ( !function_exists( 'register_sidebar_widget' ))
return;

function n2wp_latest_cpt($args) {
global $post;
extract($args);

// These are our own options
$options = get_option( 'n2wp_latest_cpt' );
$title = $options['title']; // Widget title
$phead = $options['phead']; // Heading format
$ptype = $options['ptype']; // Post type
$pshow = $options['pshow']; // Number of Tweets

$beforetitle = '';
$aftertitle = '';

// Output
echo $before_widget;

if ($title) echo $beforetitle . $title . $aftertitle;

$pq = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => $ptype, 'showposts' => $pshow ));
if( $pq->have_posts() ) :
?>  
    <div class="flex">
        <?php while($pq->have_posts()) : $pq->the_post(); ?>

          <div class="left">
            <?php
                $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    echo '<div class="menu_image" style="background: url('. $url.')">';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<div class="menu_image fallback_menus_image">';
                    echo '</div>';
                }  
            ?>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="left">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                        <ul>
                            <li><?php the_field('game_offer'); ?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

          </div>  

<?php wp_reset_query();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<!-- NEEDS FIX: to display link to full list of posts page
<?php $obj = get_post_type_object($ptype); ?>
<div class="latest_cpt_icon"><a href="<?php site_url('/'.$obj->query_var); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php _e( 'View all ' . $obj->labels->name . ' posts' ); ?>&rarr;</a></div>
//-->

<?php
// echo widget closing tag
echo $after_widget;
}

/**
* Widget settings form function
*/
function n2wp_latest_cpt_control() {

// Get options
$options = get_option( 'n2wp_latest_cpt' );
// options exist? if not set defaults
if ( !is_array( $options ))
$options = array(
'title' => 'Latest Posts',
'phead' => 'h2',
'ptype' => 'post',
'pshow' => '5'
);
// form posted?
if ( $_POST['latest-cpt-submit'] ) {
$options['title'] = strip_tags( $_POST['latest-cpt-title'] );
$options['phead'] = $_POST['latest-cpt-phead'];
$options['ptype'] = $_POST['latest-cpt-ptype'];
$options['pshow'] = $_POST['latest-cpt-pshow'];
update_option( 'n2wp_latest_cpt', $options );
}
// Get options for form fields to show
$title = $options['title'];
$phead = $options['phead'];
$ptype = $options['ptype'];
$pshow = $options['pshow'];

// The widget form fields
?>

<label for="latest-cpt-title"><?php echo __( 'Widget Title' ); ?>
<input id="latest-cpt-title" type="text" name="latest-cpt-title" size="30" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
</label>

<label for="latest-cpt-phead"><?php echo __( 'Widget Heading Format' ); ?></label>

<select name="latest-cpt-phead"><option selected="selected" value="h2">H2 - <h2></h2></option><option selected="selected" value="h3">H3 - <h3></h3></option><option selected="selected" value="h4">H4 - <h4></h4></option><option selected="selected" value="strong">Bold - <strong></strong></option></select><select name="latest-cpt-ptype"><option value="">- <?php echo __( 'Select Post Type' ); ?> -</option></select><?php $args = array( 'public' => true );
$post_types = get_post_types( $args, 'names' );
foreach ($post_types as $post_type ) { ?>

<select name="latest-cpt-ptype"><option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $post_type; ?>"><?php echo $post_type;?></option></select><?php } ?>

<label for="latest-cpt-pshow"><?php echo __( 'Number of posts to show' ); ?>
<input id="latest-cpt-pshow" type="text" name="latest-cpt-pshow" size="2" value="<?php echo $pshow; ?>" />
</label>

<input id="latest-cpt-submit" type="hidden" name="latest-cpt-submit" value="1" />
<?php
}

wp_register_sidebar_widget( 'widget_latest_cpt', __('Latest Custom Posts'), 'n2wp_latest_cpt' );
wp_register_widget_control( 'widget_latest_cpt', __('Latest Custom Posts'), 'n2wp_latest_cpt_control', 300, 200 );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'n2wp_latest_cpt_init' );

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Show the custom field value in custom post type plugin by using get_post_meta($post->ID, 'game_offer', true); function**

```
    <?php
    if( $pq->have_posts() ) :
    ?>  
        <div class="flex">
            <?php while($pq->have_posts()) : $pq->the_post(); ?>

              <div class="left">
                <?php
                    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); 
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        echo '<div class="menu_image" style="background: url('. $url.')">';
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<div class="menu_image fallback_menus_image">';
                        echo '</div>';
                    }  
                ?>
              </div>
              <div class="right">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="flex">
                        <div class="left">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                            <ul>
                                <li><?php
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'game_offer', true); 
?></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

              </div>  

    <?php wp_reset_query();
        echo '</div>';
    endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I still this same error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_field()

Comment: get_field() comes from the ACF plugin. Do you have it installed and activated.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: No I dont have it installed. Never used that plugin before. I created my own custom taxonomy and want to display it via the plugin

Comment: try this <?php
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_game_offer', true); 
?>

Comment: get_post_meta. Yes that is correct. I just had to delete the undescore before  "game" and it works 100%.
Please edit yor answer so I can mark as favourite..
Appreciate the support.

Comment: Hope you don't mind assisting in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036714/custom-post-type-rating-not-working by the way